# Who are the Heroes?

Tags: heroes, heroes-reborn

Through the four seasons of *Heroes*, those with powers were generally unknown to the public, and typically simply labeled as "[Evolved Humans](http://heroeswiki.com/List_of_evolved_humans)" or "Specials". After Claire Bennett went public with her powers, the Evolved Humans became known as "Evos".

In the premiere of *Heroes Reborn*, we see the phrase "**Where are the Heroes?**" written in a number of places.

Aside from the vigilante, El Vengador, no mention is made of any Evo acting as a public "hero".

**When/why did the Evolved Humans start to be referred to as "Heroes" by the public?**

[image: where are the heroes?]

[image: seriously, where are they?]

Comment: i think they refer to people like Claire? The world would have known by then and pretty bad stuff has been happening, ever since she revealed herself in the last episode of Heroes

Comment: @Nick but *why* are they being referred to as heroes? having evolved abilities does not necessarily make one a hero.

Comment: that's true- but I think they were asking a general question, just like 'where are all the good guys' and I think the evos have been doing a lot of thing 'in the name of the greater good'

Comment: @nick, as the OP, i'm pretty certain that's not what i was asking.

Comment: I think that in the web series, it was mentioned that few had taken up fighting crime and things like that till something bad happened. It's been a while since I watched it, and I could be wrong.

Comment: `Who watches the watchmen?` -> Not necessarily referring to The Watchmen. I'm not sure "Where are the heroes" refers to the Evos, but rather a *sentiment* of "There's a lot of villains in the world, where are the people to stand up to them." Do you have anything to show that "heroes", as seen in these pictures, specifically refers to here Evos?

Comment: @CreationEdge the little boy in the first episode of the new show and his uncle talk about evos and el vengador in the same breath as the graffiti across from their shop that says "where are the heroes?" in the web series, there is also an evo who goes by "herotruther".